# Insert bootstrap module into PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to show a bootstrap module dialog box as a confirm delete on a database.

So the code I have:

```
<?php

//Sample pop up

if ($delete_category_id > 0) {
           <div class="source-code runnable">
                BootstrapDialog.alert('I want banana!');
            </div>;
            //$da->delete_category($delete_category_id);
        }
?>
```

I've tried inserting **echo's** into the divs but the BootstrapDialog box doesn't work as its supposed to (or at all actually).

How can I insert this and have it work inside PHP?

Comment: I am not sure if you are closing and re-opening the php tags correctly or if you're doing that at all.

Comment: if ($delete_category_id > 0) { ?>

           <div class="source-code runnable">
...</div>
<?php
}?>

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions to this, one would be:

```
    <?php if ($delete_category_id > 0) { ?>
       <div class="source-code runnable">
            BootstrapDialog.alert('I want banana!');
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Another one would be:

```
    <?php if ($delete_category_id > 0) {
       echo <<<HTML
        <div class="source-code runnable">
            BootstrapDialog.alert('I want banana!');
        </div>
HTML;
    } ?>
```